# Nullity of a linear transformation, Tom Apostol calculus II problem

Tags: linear-algebra, integration

$Tom M Apostol, Calculus II$

$Exercise$ $ 2.4 $

$Q$ $26)$ Let V be a the linear space of all real functions continuous on [a,b]. If $ f$ $\in $ V, $g$=$T(f)$ means that

$ g(x)=\int_{a}^{b}\ f(t) sin(x-t)\,dt$ ,                                      $for$ $a \le$ x $\le$ b .

If T(f) is a linear transformation find the rank and nullity of T.

$A)$ Rank=2, Nullity= $\infty$

This is the solution at the back of the text but I don't understand how they arrived at it.

And this is my version. I understood that the dimension of the domain space
is $\infty$ since it is the set of all real continuous functions in an interval. Then I tried to calculate the null space by equating the transformation to $0$ which I assumed as the zero of that vector space. Now I assumed that in order for the integral of a function to be $0$ the function must have a zero value throughout the interval i.e

$ f(t)sin(x-t)=0 $ for all $t$ $\in$ $[a,b]$

Now since that cannot be true for $sin$ throughout an interval I thought $f(t)=0$ throughout the interval. And since there is only one function which satisfies this condition I thought the dimension of nullspace is $0$ and since dimension of domain space is already $\infty$ I thought dimension of range must also be $\infty$. Can anyone give me the complete answer and explain where I went wrong ?

Comment: "Now I assumed that in order for the integral of a function to be $0$ the function must have a zero value throughout the interval" . This is COMPLETELY INCORRECT, please forget this idea entirely. This is because when you integrate, if the function changes sign, then the positive contributions and negative contributions can cancel out to give an integral of $0$, even though the function is not identically zero. (example: $\int_0^{2\pi} \sin(x) \, dx = 0$ even though $\sin(x)$ is not identically zero on $[0,2\pi]$)

Comment: To emphasize peek-a-boo's point, as an example:

$$\int_{-\pi}^\pi \sin(x)dx = 0$$

even though $\sin(x)$ is only zero at integer multiples of $\pi$. (Of course, you can take any odd, integrable function $f(x)$ on a symmetric interval about zero $[-a,a]$, and see that $\int_{-a}^a f(x)dx=0$. $\sin(x)$ on $[-\pi,\pi]$ is just an example.)

Comment: @peek-a-boo thanks for that

Comment: just FYI, it's not directly relevant to this question's answer, but suppose you have a continuous function $g: [a,b] \to \Bbb{R}$ and $g$ does NOT change sign. In this case, if $\int_a^b g(x) \, dx = 0$, then you can conclude that $g=0$ on $[a,b]$. This is a correct theorem (notice the importance of $g$ not changing sign), and you should be careful to remember this extra hypothesis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\sin(x-t)= \sin x \cos t - \cos x \sin t$ so

$$g(x) = \sin x \int_a^b f(t) \cos t~ dt- \cos x \int_a^b f(t) \sin t~dt.$$

Define the first integral to be $A(f)$ and the second integral to be $B(f)$.  Then $$g(x)=A(f) \sin x -B(f) \cos x.$$

Thus, for any continuous function $f, T(f)=g(x)$ is always a linear combination of $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ (which are linearly independent), so $T$ has rank $2$.  Since $V$ is infinite-dimensional and $\operatorname{rank} T =2$, $T$ must have infinite nullity.